# how to remove characters from printed output in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to remove extra characters printed out in my print statement from another print statement.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
print(addedlist)  #addedlist = [9,5,1989,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for x in range(0, len(addedlist)):
    print('%d->'%addedlist[x],end="")

print('\n')
```

the output of this looks like this:

```
[9, 5, 1989, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
9->5->1989->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->
```

I am trying to remove the last `->` characters. I tried doing :

```
print(addedlist)  #addedlist = [9,5,1989,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for x in range(0, len(addedlist)):
     print('%d->'%addedlist[x],end="")

print('\b\b\n')
```

but it didn't work.

How would i go about accomplishing this ?

**EDIT:**

Just some clarification, I know i can change my original print statement to print it more correctly to avoid trailing `->` ... I am after a solution for how to erase trailing '->' this once the mistake has been made

Comment: You'll need something more powerful than just print commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice you wants to play with `carriage return` commands. First you need to learn both `\b` (moves the active position to the previous position) and `\r` (moves the active position to the start of line) *works for current active line*.
I think you are working on command line interpreter; at which you explicitly press enter for next line.
On command line interpreter use `;`  as follows:

```
>>> print("abb", end=""); print("\b\bcc")
acc
>>> print("a->", end=""); print("\b\b  ")
>>> a
```

If you are using some script then your code should work, see:

```
Upload$ cat s.py
print ("abcd->", end="")
print ("\b\b  ")
Upload$ python3.2 s.py
abcd    # notice -> is removed
```

But this is not much useful, correct approach is what [Aशwini चhaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/awini-haudhary) has shown in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23149489/1673391).

Edit: I found you mistake in your code

```
print('%d->' % addedlist[x], end="")    
print('\b\b\n')
```

You use `'\b'` to moves the active position to the previous position, but you don't overwrite `"->"`, you just outputs `'\n'` that shift cursors to next line, you should rectify your code as below.

```
print('%d->' % addedlist[x], end="")    
print('\b\b   \n')
#          ^^^  /b then overwrite with spaces
```

Run at Linux shell as `$ python scriptname.py` (For command line Python's interpreter you can use something [like code I written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkC2v.png), it is just to play, use `str.join` or use `sep` parameter in `print()`).

Comment: thanks mate. Looking at your command line interpreter code, how would you impliment that in my for loop code ?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that helps in command prompt... Why doesn't this work in python shell though ??

Comment: @sukhvir No it is working on python shell with `;` as I shown. Note: on python interpreter you explicitly enters to run a comment that also give newline at output.

Comment: @sukhvir After playing around 5 min with your code I could write a code for command line interceptor [Copy-past this code](http://codepad.org/ohKKXnH8) at Python's command line interpreter that will run [like this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tkC2v.png)

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.join`:

```
>>> s = [9,5,1989,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> print ('->'.join(map(str, s)))
9->5->1989->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9
```

Or better `print()` with `sep` as `'->'`:

```
>>> print(*s, sep='->')
9->5->1989->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9
```

Comment: thanks .. I am aware of how to change my print statement to print it correctly .. I am interested in correcting it after wrong printing has been done

Comment: @sukhvir No once you have printed on stdout you can't overwrite it (if you are not working in [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library). So the answer posted here is exactly do what you wants, otherwise learn ncurses mode.