# Saving variables in Python as columns without brackets

Tags: python, numpy, save

I have a code which returns some variables that I would like to later on use in another program. However, the output doesn't look like I want it to. The rows are within brackets [], and I would like to have them removed.

I have found the following question that deals with something similar; however, I am saving the variable, not printing it on the screen:

[how to remove characters from printed output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149432/how-to-remove-characters-from-printed-output-in-python)

This is where the variable is defined, the libraries used are chaospy and numpy.

```py
nodes, weights = cp.generate_quadrature(order, dist, rule="G", sparse=True)
nodes_trans = nodes.transpose()
```

And this is where the variable is saved

```py
with open('nodes_smolyak_trans.txt', 'w') as ndsT:
    for itemndsT in nodes_trans:
        ndsT.write("%s\n" % itemndsT)
ndsT.close()
```

Also,  dist, mentioned above is defined as

```py
dist = cp.J(wX, wY, pX, pY)
```

And all it's compoents are defined equally as

```py
windX = cp.Uniform(0, 100)
```

Now, all rows of my output looks like this:

[50.         50.         50.         21.13248654]

I would like them to be instead simply

50. 50. 50. 21.13248654

If the number of rows is small, I can manually remove them by hand, but when the output contains hundreds, I waste too much time, so any sugestion to remove the brackets manually is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that `itemndsT` is a list type, which is why when you write it to the file it includes the square brackets. You'll need to format it into a string yourself before writing it. There are a few ways you can do this, but using [the `join` string function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) is one of the simplest:

```
for itemndsT in nodes_trans:
    item_str = " ".join(map(str,itemndsT))
    ndsT.write("%s\n" % item_str)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however, if I implement your sugestion an error appears; TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.float64 found in the line item_str = " ".join(itemndsTB). Note that I have written your for loop is between:  with open('nodes_smolyak_transB.txt', 'w') as ndsTB: and ndsTB.close()

Comment: Ah ok, all you need to do now then is convert all the numpy.float64's that are in the list to strings. You can do that easily by using map - I'll add it to my answer.